# Hyperlinks in custom Atom feed don't work in feed readers

Tags: xml, atom-feed, feedburner

I'm trying to generate an Atom feed for my link blog and distribute it with FeedBurner. I've run into a strange problem where neither the original XML file on my server, or FeedBurner's feed, display links in feed readers.

Hopefully I can link these directly since it's a problem with the specific feed -- the FAQ wasn't really clear. If not I will be glad to remove the links and paste in the files, but that seemed like it would add a lot of clutter to the question.

I'm not too familiar with generating RSS/Atom feeds, and running it through the validator shows that it passes. Additionally, the links display fine on Feedburner's "frontend" page. This is why I don't understand why Google Reader et al don't display the links.

Without further ado, [here is the original xml file][1] and [here is feedburner's resulting page][2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XHTML elements in Atom feeds need to have the [correct XHTML namespace](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml) specified. Compare this version:

```
<content type="xhtml" xmlns='xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
        <p>...</p>
```

with the namespaces in your current feed:

```
<content type="xhtml" xmlns='xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <div>
        <p>...</p>
```